# Search and Replace string in file in C#

Tags: c#, replace

I am trying to create a small form in C# to find one string in a TMX file (xml) and replace it for another. Then it would create an output file with all the modifications.
The form contains a search button to locate the file in the local disk and a REPLACE button which it would change "srclang="*all*"" for "srclang="en-US"".
So far I have the following:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (FileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            if (DialogResult.OK == fileDialog.ShowDialog())
            {
                string filename = fileDialog.FileName;

                textBox1.Text = fileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       StreamWriter writer = null;
        Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        replacements.Add("*all*", "en-US");
        // ... further replacement entries ...

        using (writer = File.CreateText("output.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(textBox1.Text))
            {
                bool replacementMade = false;
                foreach (var replacement in replacements)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith(replacement.Key))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{1}",
                            replacement.Key, replacement.Value));
                        replacementMade = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!replacementMade)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }

        File.Replace("output.txt", textBox1.Text, "ORIGINAL_TMX_FILE.bak");
    }
    }
}
```

This code is from Dave R. from this site, it really works with TXT files but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am totally a newbie here.
If anyone could help me write some lines to make it work, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: If it's xml, you really want to be using the XML features of C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470103/best-way-to-manipulate-xml-in-net

Comment: Can you post an example of the section of the XML file which needs the replacement?

Comment: Hi Chris, I would need to change a string from the header (srclang="*all*" for srclang="en-US"): <header
  creationtool=""
  creationtoolversion="2.98"
  datatype="xml"
  segtype="paragraph"
  adminlang="en"
  srclang="*all*"
  o-tmf="TM"
 >
 </header>  thanks everybody for the help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing that could work would be to use these methods

- [File.WriteAllLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [File.ReadAllLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

as in the example below:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    outputFileName,
    File.ReadAllLines(inputFileName)
        .Select(line => line.Replace(@"srclang=""en-US""", @"srclang=""all"""));
```

If there could be whitespace in the search text, you could replace the call to `string.Replace` with a `Regex.Replace`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're trying to do and the following segment is the essence of your code:

```
if (line.StartsWith(replacement.Key))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{1}",
            replacement.Key, replacement.Value));
        replacementMade = true;
        break;
    }
```

If your dictionary will always have one element, you only have to change the parameter of the WriteLine call. You're writing *only* the replacement value instead of the whole line with the replacements done on it. You might want to have something like

```
writer.WriteLine(line.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value)
```

If you want to check for several replacements, store the replaced line in the inner loop and only write it at the end and remove the break command.

Another unrelated observation: the `replacement.Key` parameter in the WriteLine call is omitted since `{1}` refers to the second additional parameter (counting starts from 0).