# Use XPath with XML namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, default-namespace

I want to process the xml below with XPath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="Cloud" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2014-01.2.3">
  <Role name="Worker">
    <Instances count="2" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="setting1" value="value1" />
      <Setting name="setting2" value="value2" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Certificates>
    </Certificates>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Tere's a `xmlns` for the root element.

My code is this:

```
    XElement doc = XElement.Load(xmlFilePath);
    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    ns.AddNamespace("prefix", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration");
    XElement settingDiagConnectionString = doc.XPathSelectElement("//prefix:ServiceConfiguration/Role/ConfigurationSettings/Setting[1]", ns);  // <===== always return null.
    settingDiagConnectionString.SetAttributeValue("value", "hello, world!");
```

But the `settingDiagConnectionString` is always null.

Why?

### Add 1

Thanks har07.

After adding prefix for every element, the following code works:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(cscfgPath);
    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    ns.AddNamespace("prefix", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration");

    XmlNode settingDiagConnectionString = doc.SelectNodes("/prefix:ServiceConfiguration/prefix:Role/prefix:ConfigurationSettings/prefix:Setting[1]", ns)[0];
    settingDiagConnectionString.Attributes["value"].Value = "hello,world!";
```

**But the following code still don't work. The `settingDiagConnectionString` is still null.  Why?**

```
    XElement doc = XElement.Load(cscfgPath);
    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    ns.AddNamespace("prefix", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration");

    XElement settingDiagConnectionString = doc.XPathSelectElement("/prefix:ServiceConfiguration/prefix:Role/prefix:ConfigurationSettings/prefix:Setting[1]", ns);
    settingDiagConnectionString.SetAttributeValue("value", "hello, world!");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default namespace has different nature. The element where the default namespace declared and all of it's descendant without different namespace declaration considered in the same default namespace. Therefore, you need to use the prefix for all descendats as well. This XPath worked fine for me :

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
ns.AddNamespace("prefix", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration");
XElement settingDiagConnectionString = doc.XPathSelectElement("//prefix:Role/prefix:ConfigurationSettings/prefix:Setting[1]", ns); 
settingDiagConnectionString.SetAttributeValue("value", "hello, world!");
```

**UPDATE :**

Responding to your update. That's because you're using `XElement`. In this case, `doc` it self already represents `<ServiceConfiguration>` element so you don't need to include "ServiceConfiguration" in the XPath :

```
/prefix:Role/prefix:ConfigurationSettings/prefix:Setting[1]
```

..or use `XDocument` instead of `XElement` if you want to make it work using the same XPath as for `XmlDocument`.

Comment: see my brief response in **UPDATE** section

Comment: Really appreciate your answer.